# How to translate SQL `cast as` to Ecto DSL?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following dummy query

```
SELECT * FROM dummy_table
ORDER BY CAST(number_in_string AS DECIMAL)
```

How to write that in Ecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order_by` a fragment like this:

```
fragment("CAST(? as DECIMAL)", dt.number_in_string)
```

`from(p in Post, order_by: [asc: fragment("CAST(? as DECIMAL)", p.id)])` generates the following query:

> SELECT p0."id", p0."title", p0."user_id", p0."inserted_at", p0."updated_at" FROM "posts" AS p0 ORDER BY CAST(p0."id" as DECIMAL)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`type/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.5/Ecto.Query.API.html#type/2).

```
from u in User, where: u.id == type(^"5", :integer)
```

Which generated the following query

> SELECT u0."id", u0."first_name", u0."last_name", u0."email", u0."encrypted_password", u0."inserted_at", u0."updated_at" FROM "users" AS u0 WHERE (u0."id" = $1::integer) [5]